# Add two variables in django templates?

Tags: python, django, templates

```
{% with a=pro_details.product_quantity|add:product_details.product_quantity %}
```

I need to add two variables in django templates using with and add.

Comment: Application logic should stay out of the templates. You should do this in the view.

Comment: I know that it can be done in view but my requirement is to add it in the templates.Can you please help me with that?

Comment: It cannot be done without writing additional code, in which case it's either one line in the view, or a whole new file for creating complex custom tags. Logic must be done in the view, that's what it is *for*. What is the rationale you have for forcing that into a template?

Comment: logic is set in view i cant change it there for now so i must have to add it to templates

Comment: Not doable. What you actually have to do is see how to change the view. Is it that of a third-party package? Then subclass and extend it. Is it under the responsibility of another devteam? Then get in touch with them so they add the data you need. Templates just aren't the place for that and won't do it.

Comment: yes spectras you are right and i know it can be done in view but  still is there any way it can be done in template and not in view. Thanks

Comment: What isn't working? What does this code do currently that you don't expect?

Comment: I want to add two values and store it in another variable and use it.

Answer (score 7):

You can use custom template tags for this to achieve.

**The templatetags/custom_tags.py file:**

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def add(a, b):
    return a+b
```

**The template part, with our tag call:**

```
{% load video_tags %}
```

(where you want to use)

```
{% add 5 6 %}
```

you can consult to this link as well. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: 'custom_tags' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of ... etc